# Two virtual machine instance with same network on same host

Tags: ip, virtualization

Is this possible to have two (or more) instances of a virtual machine on a host with the same IP address (like 192.168.0.X)?
What are the possible ways of implementing this?
I need the two virtual machines be accessible using the same address from the host.

Comment: Do you mean to setup `NAT`?

Comment: No something more like network namespace but simpler.

Comment: You create an IP packet to this address on the host. How shall the host decide which VM to send it to? Sending it to both would work only in very special cases (no TCP; no UDP answers).

Answer (score 0):

It's possible just like it's possible with non-virtual machines, but you will be creating an [IP Address conflict](http://wiki-errors.com/ip-address-conflict/%20%22IP%20Address%20conflict) which is generally considered to be a Bad Idea.  You will encounter the same problems in remotely accessing one machine or the other that you would have in a non-virtual context.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible only if one IP is active anytime (virtual IP). Both the virtual machines will need to have another IP address which can be used for administrative tasks. services will be bound to the virtual IP and that IP will be active only on one machine using some software like `KeepAlived` which will switch over automatically if the active virtual machine crashes.